# how to create dump for specific schema in postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I have a Postgres database "rafiu" with many schemas namely test1, test2, test3. In this I want to dump the test2 schema and its data. I tried with the following query

```
pg_dump -U postgres -n test2 -t t1 -t t2 rafiu > test_schema.sql
```

but it dumped public.t1, public.t2 tables instead of test2 schema tables in the resultant dump file.

Kindly suggest me how to create a dump specific specific schema in a DB.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`-n test2` means to dump schema `test2`.

If you want to dump table `test2.t1` and `test2.t2`, you might want to try the following statement:

```
pg_dump -U postgres -t test2.t1 -t test2.t2 rafiu > test_schema.sql
```

Comment: How about the whole data from one schema? Using his example, get all tables from `test2`?

Comment: I had the same problem and had spent a couple of days trying to resolve the issue (online searching, trying various ways).  In my case, when I specified a schema and tables in the schema to dump, I got no matching  tables found errors.  Apparently pg_dump only searches the public schema for tables specified with -t and/or -T without prefixing the table names with the schema name.  By intuition I assumed that the search would be done in the specified schema for specified tables instead in the public schema.  I think the man page could make it more explicit about the behaves of -n/-N and -t/-T.